# ListView area increases when I put image or text

Tags: android, listview

I have created `ListView`s but when I put an image or a text, the height of the listView increases. How can I reduce this?
Thanks

```
<ListView
        android:dividerHeight="2px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
         />
```

Comment: Put a fixed height to the listview instead of using wrap_content, or wrap it on another layout and use match_parent so it will not grow

Comment: Always set `match_parent` as height with `ListView`. Using `wrap_content` is not very nice, performance-wise.

Comment: if you want a maximum height to your listView, add
        android:maxHeight="height"

Comment: Use `Match_Parent` as `List View` height.